# The slopes of the graph of $ \cos cx $ belong to the interval $ [- c, \: c] $. Find the missing numbers:

Tags: calculus

The slopes of the graph of $ \cos cx $ belong to the interval $ [- c, \: c] $. Find the missing numbers,

If $ | x-a | < (?) $ Then $ | \cos 2x- \cos 2a | <\varepsilon $

If $ | y-b | <\delta $ then $ | \cos 3y - \cos 3b | < (?) $

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6slX.png)

Trying to solve it, I was thinking that a "triangle" with slope 2 can be formed, then $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for the first exercise...

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate $\cos x$?

Comment: @MarkBennet you suggest I do:

$f (x) '= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f (x) -f (a)}{x-a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of derivative says

$$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\cos(cx)-\cos(ca)}{x-a} = -c\sin(ca).$$

Thus, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta_0 > 0$ such that when $|x - a| < \delta_0$,

$$\left| \frac{\cos(cx)-\cos(ca)}{x-a} + c \sin(ca) \right| < \epsilon \implies |\cos(cx) - \cos(ca)| < \left( \epsilon + |c \sin(ca)| \right)|x-a|$$

using the (reverse) triangle inequality. Thus, for you question,

$$ \delta = \min \left (\delta_0 , \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + |c \sin(ca)|} \right) > 0 $$ will suffice.

Comment: By the way, you are right, $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ will work.

Comment: Formally, how could it be justified?

Comment: I guess I should have said that $2$ works if $c < 2$, because then $2$ is a larger denominator than the denominator I have for my $\delta$. If $c > > 2$, then $2$ might not work.